# Why is my ngRoute in AngularJS not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am learning some AngularJS at school and we were asked to implement routing for our project but I am having some trouble with ngRoute:

Here is my js file (app.js):

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
      templateUrl: "index.html",
    })
    .when("/jadwal", {
      templateUrl: "showJadwal.html",
      controller: "jadwalController",
    })
    .when("/jadwalUjian", {
      templateUrl: "showJadwalUjian.html",
      controller: "jadwalUjianController",
    });
});
```

These are the files I have imported in my html:

```
    <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/app.js"></script>
```

These are the hrefs:

```
<div id="navbar" class="collapse">
                <ul>
                    <li class="active"><a href="#!/" data-nav-section="home">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#!jadwal">Jadwal</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#!jadwalUjian">Jadwal Ujian</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-nav-section="skills">To Do List</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Plus I have also placed `<div ng-view></div>`

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Not related to your question, but I'd strongly advice you to ask to learn Angular instead of AngularJS, if at all possible. AngularJS is outdated, and has been replaced by Angular.

Comment: @Cerbrus I strongly agree with you, my school's curriculum is pretty outdated and they taught us AngularJS instead of Angular so for this project I, unfortunately, do not have much choice. Either way, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Expanding on Cerbrus's comment. AngularJS 1.5 introduced components which was where the framework started promoting component-architecture which is a more modern approach that may translate to newer frameworks. If you have a course outline, see if components are covered as that will be a valuable concept.

Comment: Could you clarify the issue you are having and any associated errors? Also a plunkr, jsFiddle, or CodePen would go a long way in helping debug your issue.

Comment: @MarkClark Thank you for the advice, I looked into the AngularJS documentation and fiddled with the routing syntax of my code and it is now working (I use `#/` instead of `#!`). The issue was simply I could not get the routing to work despite following numerous AngularJS tutorials and references.